# Serving http contents through secure network(https)

Tags: http, https

I am working on a project which uses secure network(https) but it contains a flash player which plays videos from a third party URL and is not on a secure network.

Everytime the player is used the page shows a insecure network warning.

Is there a way I can make the pages to avoid the security warning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In this setup, no. The warning is there explicitly because you are mixing HTTP and HTTPS on one page.

The only way to not get it is to go all HTTP, or all HTTPS